# Error while trying to Deploy GWT application to GAE

Tags: java, google-app-engine, gwt, web-deployment

I am trying to deploy my project to app engine, but after the compilation, when it tries to deploy the app I get this error:

```
Deploying:
    Uploading 27 files.
    Uploaded 6 files.
    Uploaded 12 files.
    Uploaded 18 files.
    Uploaded 24 files.
    Initializing precompilation...
    Sending batch containing 13 file(s) totaling 1172KB.
    Exception in flushing batch payload, so sending 1 by 1...Error posting to URL: https://appengine.google.com/api/appversion/addfiles?=&app_id=xxxx&version=3&
500 Internal Server Error

<html><head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
<title>500 Server Error</title>
</head>
<body text=#000000 bgcolor=#ffffff>
<h1>Error: Server Error</h1>
<h2>The server encountered an error and could not complete your request.<p>If the problem persists, please <A HREF="http://code.google.com/appengine/community.html">report</A> your problem and mention this error message and the query that caused it.</h2>
<h2></h2>
</body></html>

     on backend null.
com.google.appengine.tools.admin.HttpIoException: Error posting to URL: https://appengine.google.com/api/appversion/addfile?path=img%2F0.png&app_id=xxxxxxx=3&
500 Internal Server Error

<html><head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
<title>500 Server Error</title>
</head>
<body text=#000000 bgcolor=#ffffff>
<h1>Error: Server Error</h1>
<h2>The server encountered an error and could not complete your request.<p>If the problem persists, please <A HREF="http://code.google.com/appengine/community.html">report</A> your problem and mention this error message and the query that caused it.</h2>
<h2></h2>
</body></html>
```

Any idea why could happened?
I have to say that my last deploy was yesterday and was working, and from then I changed something minor!

Could the app engine servers to be down?

**UPDATE:** Now is working perfectly fine, perhaps GAE was down or smth.

Answer (score 0):

There was an issue with application deployment earlier today. For more information you can follow [this bug report](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=7535).